# What's the proper way to log big data to organize and store it with Hadoop, and query it using Hive?

Tags: hadoop, logging, amazon-web-services, bigdata, amazon-emr

So basically I have apps on different platforms that are sending logging data to my server.  It's a node server that essentially accepts a payload of log entries and it saves them to their respective log files (as write stream buffers, so it is fast), and creates a new log file whenever one fills up.

The way I'm storing my logs is essentially one file per "endpoint", and each log file consists of space separated values that correspond to metrics.  For example, a player event log structure might look like this:

`timestamp user mediatype event`

and the log entry would then look like this

`1433421453 bob iPhone play`

Based off of reading documentation, I think this format is good for something like Hadoop.  The way I *think* this works, is I will store these logs on a server, then run a cron job that periodically moves these files to S3.  From S3, I could use those logs as a source for a Hadoop cluster using Amazon's EMR.  From there, I could query it with Hive.

Does this approach make sense?  Are there flaws in my logic?  How should I be saving/moving these files around for Amazon's EMR? Do I need to concatenate all my log files into one giant one?

Also, what if I add a metric to a log in the future?  Will that mess up all my previous data?

I realize I have a lot of questions, that's because I'm new to Big Data and need a solution.  Thank you very much for your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large volume of log dump that changes periodically, the approach you laid out makes sense.  Using EMRFS, you can directly process the logs from S3 (which you probably know).

As you 'append' new log events to Hive, the part files will be produced. So, you dont have to concatenate them ahead of loading them to Hive.

(on day 0, the logs are in some delimited form, loaded to Hive, Part files are produced as a result of various transformations.  On subsequent cycles, new events/logs will be appened to those part files.)

Adding new fields on an ongoing basis is a challenge.  You can create new data structures/sets and Hive tables and join them.  But the joins are going to be slow.  So, you may want to define fillers/placeholders in your schema.

If you are going to receive streams of logs (lots of small log files/events) and need to run near real time analytics, then have a look at Kinesis.

(also test drive Impala.  It is faster)

.. my 2c.

Comment: I'm not actually concerned about parsing and indexing log files...I already wrote a service that does this, it needed to be custom.  My question is more along the lines of how do I run Hive queries over this data using Amazon's Elastic Map Reduce